# Blender 2.78 not using filmic color management on MacOS Sierra

Tags: osx, filmic-blender

I have already installed Filmic Blender in the Application (ShowPackageContents>>Resources>>2.78>>datafiles). I have renamed default colormangement to colomanagement_old. However, Blender still does not use filmic blender. How do I get blender to use filmic colormanagent.

Edit:
I attempted using a recent daily build of blender and am still unable to use filmic blender. Furthermore, I checked to see whether filmic was installed under the colormanagement settings, and it was there. But, it says that I am missing the add_mesh_ant_landscape files. I don't know if that has anything to do with it, but I thought I'd include it. Any ideas on why I don't have the options? Futhermore, if I try clicking on the filmic blender install, I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adchinnasami/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.78/scripts/addons/filmic_blender.py", line 57, in execute
    os.rename(cmpath, opath)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/private/var/folders/nh/tc37x77n3933f4mxk74njl6r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/216BC7FE-9956-42E3-AC0E-8EF0B854241A/d/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.78/datafiles/colormanagement' -> '/private/var/folders/nh/tc37x77n3933f4mxk74njl6r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/216BC7FE-9956-42E3-AC0E-8EF0B854241A/d/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.78/datafiles/colormanagement_old'

location: :-1

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try a recent daily build from builder.blender.org. Even though they are still called 2.78, they are actually pre-release builds of 2.79, which has Filmic built-in.

Comment: I tried that, but I am still unable to use filmic blender. (I have edited the original question with more detail).

Comment: I don't know enough about macOS to be of further help, unfortunately.

Comment: In 2.79 you can use filmic by simply selecting Filmic under View in the Color Management panel. You can remove the file /Users/adchinnasami/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.78/scripts/addons/filmic_blender.py.

Comment: Under view, I am only getting a default option. The other options, such as filmic, are not present, even thought they are clearly in the colormanagement settings when looking in the package contents. Any idea why?